# Ventilation intake for small room

Tags: ventilation

So I have a storage/utility room. High humidity (Indonesia). Dimensions approx 3.3 x 3m x 3m . It's still under construction, and there are no windows, just a door. Material is AAC (lightweight concrete) 60cmx20cmx10cm blocks to three walls, and red brick (dimensions maybe 20x10x5cm) to west wall.

There will likely be a washing machine in the room, maybe with integrated dryer.

I have an extractor fan (continuous: http://powerdiscount.co.uk/greenwood-cv100-constant-volume-continuously-running-extractor-fan-382-p.asp), which I plan to fit. But somebody pointed out there's no intake!

The room is obviously more-or-less square, and the walls adjoin (moving around clockwise) North: hall-way area, less airflow. East: outside, South: outside (but front of property and I'd prefer to avoid this, West: large open-plan room with very good ventilation to outside.

So it seems like if I extract the air out through the east wall then I need to suck air from the outside. So I need to put some kind of vent opposite on the west wall. What kind of thing should I be fitting?

Something like this? https://www.amazon.co.uk/M141-Marley-anodised-Aluminium-Louvered/dp/B009T5GOW0/

Or this? http://www.bhl.co.uk/rytons-multifix-airbrick-9-inch-x-3-inch-brown.html

How much do I need?

The area adjoining is an office area, so sound from the storage room is not really a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a continuous fan would be a bathroom exhaust fan hooked to a moisture-sensing switch, or a [humidity sensing bathroom fan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0014ZYZCY). Both are commercially available and it would save your fan from running 24/7. You can then attach it to flexible ducting and put a dryer vent or roof vent to exhaust the moist air. Better still is a large bathroom fan makes very little noise.

Comment: I still need an intake for air to circulate though, right?

Comment: Possibly. Is the door to the room an exterior door with a gasket?

Comment: it's an interior door, and it's quite a tight fit. no gasket just solid hardwood

Comment: It might work as-is but never hurts to have an intake

Comment: a fan? or just a grille or ventilation brick?

Comment: Just a grill should do. The exhaust fan should do all the work

Comment: Yes, you can even put the grille on the door itself if you're so inclined.